# Equivalent system to first-order logic in Shoenfield's

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In Shoenfield's Mathematical Logic, chapter 4, problem 6, it asks us to show that the following formal system is equivalent to first-order logic (the problem is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge8ZT.png)).

I suspect that there is a mistake in the not-or rule because from it I can derive a theorem that shouldn't be in FOL (namely, define A and C to be any False proposition and B to be a True proposition).

Thanks!

Comment: I’ve not looked at the system as a whole, but that rule would at least make sense if it were: infer $\neg(A\lor B)\lor C$ from $\neg A\lor\color{red}C$ and $\neg\color{red}B\lor C$.

Comment: Thanks, Brian Scott!

Comment: You’re welcome!